# How to fetch text of a specific element of a table in webdriverio?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I have a table of 10 rows and 4 columns and I am trying to get the text of the first column and put it in array using webdriverio.

```
    getItemName(rowIndex){
    let numberOfRows = this.getNumberOfItemsInTheTable();
    let arr = []; 
    $$('table.bmv-tableClass > tbody > tr'.map((result) => {
        arr.push(result.$('td.bmv-columnClass').getText());
    });
    return arr[1];
}
```

I tried this but I get an error of: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined .
Any idea how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi did the answer provided help?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing a `)` after the first element `$$('table.bmv-tableClass > tbody > tr'`.

Try using this:

```
$$("table.bmv-tableClass > tbody > tr").map((result) => {
  arr.push(result.$("td.bmv-columnClass").getText());
});
```

If still does not work please share the DOM of your table.

Comment: Alternatively, you can move the `td` selector to be just: `const results = $$("table.bmv-tableClass > tbody > tr > td.bmv-columnClass").map($td => $td.getText());`